# How to add conditions with VUE for classes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

it's possible to make conditions with Vue to change add class according to the text loaded on the doom?

I have a list with colors name

```html
<span>yellow</span>
<span>red</span>
<span>grey</span>
```

I want to make a condition for example if the name text is yellow I want to add class "color_yellow" and so on

Comment: This will help you https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: how you check "name text" is it an input field?

Comment: no, it's loaded with liquid as a loop on the span element <span> {{ value }} </span>

Answer (score 2):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      colors: ['yellow', 'red', 'grey']
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.color_yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
.color_red {
  color: red;
}
.color_grey {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(color, i) in colors" :key="i">
      <span :class="`color_${color}`">{{ color }}</span>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
<span :class="color.colorName">{{ color.colorName }}</span>
```

In css,

```
.yellow { color: yellow }
.red { color: red }
```

For more details, you can check https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html